# Save Video SD Card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Hello How I can Save Video On external card I have android 4.4.2

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Output");
if (!folder.exists()) folder.mkdir();

String out = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Output/" +
             DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_kk-mm-ss", new Date().getTime()) +
             ".mp4";
```